# Remove subdomains with awk or sed

Tags: shell, awk, sed, domain

How to remove all subdomains in a text file? I think I need to delete everything before and including the '.'?

input:

```
unix.stackexchange.com
www.example.org
example.example.tld
```

Expected output:

```
stackexchange.com
example.org
example.tld
```

**EDIT:**

Domains without subdomains should stay untouched. The full domain only should be touched if it has a subdomain. In other words, two '.'s or more.

google.com must stay google.com
input:

```
google.com
mail.google.com
```

Expected output:

```
google.com
google.com
```

Comment: Be aware that some types of domains may have a second level administrative component. For example `bbc.co.uk` and `leeds.ac.uk`, where the `co.uk`/`ac.uk` have a second level administrative component. It would not be correct to strip all `*.co.uk` domains back to `co.uk` and expect to retain meaning. To further complicate matters the UK's second level component is now optional, so there could be not only `example.co.uk` but also a separate and distinct `example.uk` (no administrative second level).

Comment: How should input like simply `google.com` be handled? Add that to your question.

Comment: Good one Ed, I didn't thought about that

Comment: @roaima I don't work with UK domains so I don't need it. Adding that request to my question would make the answer more complete and useful for the forum, but it would make existing answers 'half valid'. I will mark your answer as valid If you can answer my question where in the answer the UK second level administrative component intact remain

Comment: Unfortunately I have neither a list of the TLDs where there are two administrative levels nor good heuristics/rules to address them. If your requirement doesn't touch such domains that's fine. On the off chance it did I wanted to warn you of the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sample data

```
www.google.com
prep.ai.mit.edu
```

to keep last two top domain,

using `sed`

```
sed 's/.*\.\(.*\..*\)/\1/'
```

where

- `.*\.` greedy match any char (including dot) and a dot
- `\( \)` remember matched string
- `.*\..*` any char(1) multiple time, a dot any char multiple time
- (1) will not match dot due to greedyness above.
- `\1` recall first remembered string

using (gnu) `grep`

```
grep -Eo '[^.]*.[^.]*$' data
google.com
mit.edu
```

- regex pattern (`[^.]*.[^.]*$`) read mostly as above, except `$` which anchor to end of line.

---

to remove first subdomain, using `sed` (left as information, specification changed)

```
sed -e 's/^[^.]*\.//' data
google.com
ai.mit.edu
```

where

- `^[^.]*\.` read as `^` begin of line , `[^.]` not a `.`, `*` multiple time, `\.`  a dot
- replaced by nothing.
- as noted in comment, `sed` can be shorterned to `'s/[^.]*.//'` (provided line do not start with dot ).

Comment: I like to write scripts for maintainability. (1) If lines don't start with a dot, the `^` is superfluous. (2) If we know that each line contains a dot, the dot doesn't need to be escaped because the char after `[^.]*` will always be a dot. (1+2) So make it easy to read `sed 's/[^.]*.//'` (3) Option `-o` is GNU-only, I think. This should be mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to strip off the first subdomain:

```bash
cut -d . -f 2- input
```

If you have multiple levels of subdomains like `sub2.sub1.domain.com` you can use `cut` in combination with `rev` to keep the last two elements of the domain:

```bash
rev input | cut -d . -f -2 |  rev
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for awk or sed

Comment: @xorghelpneed cut will be faster and if anything more portable.

Comment: This is the best solution. A more comprehensible (and messy) solution needs to take into account available TLDs as listed in https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt.

Comment: +1 for the `rev ... rev` approach

Answer (score 3):

If we can be sure that the domain will be the last two `.`-separated fields on the line, you can use:

```
$ awk -F. -v OFS='.' '{print $(NF-1),$NF}' file
stackexchange.com
example.org
example.tld
```

Or `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/.*\.\([^.]*\..*\)$/\1/' file
stackexchange.com
example.org
example.tld
```

And, if your `sed` supports `-E`, slightly cleaner:

```
 sed -E 's/.*\.([^.]*\..*)$/\1/' file
stackexchange.com
example.org
example.tld
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like in awk can do the work:

```
awk -F. 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {sub(".*" $1 FS,"")}1' input_file
```

And this work independently of the level of subdomains.

Comment: This only removes a single level of subdomains.

Comment: @r_31415, correct, it remove the 1st token

Comment: That would fail if `$1` contained regexp metachars or was a substring of a different $1 since the FS is `.` which means "any character" when used in the `sub()`. Also the `.*` at the start would match anything through the whole line so it'd match anywhere in the middle of the URL.

Comment: @EdMorton, agree, but I expect hostname to be sanitized well and contain only permitted chars :)

Comment: Even with that, though, you still have the problem that input like `foo.foobar.com` would become `sub(".*" "foo" ".","")` since `$1` would be `foo` and `FS` is `.` which would output `ar.com` instead of `foobar.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard `sed` to remove everything but the last and next-to-last component:

```
sed 's/.*\.\(.*\..*\)/\1/'
```

Unfortunally, this regexp looks like a forest after the storm. Let's build it up in steps:

- `.*\.` is any number of characters (including dots), ending with a dot
- later in the expression we require another dot, so the `.*\.` will match everything from the beginning to the next-to-last dot
- now we are sure that the remains of the line only have one dot (the literal one, so `.*\..*` is enough to match the rest
- We place this remains inside `\(\)`, so it can be recycled in the replacement as `\1`, while everything else is thrown away

Visual explanation:

```
subdomain.domain.tld
sub1.sub2.domain.tld
`--v----´ `-v--´ `v´
   .*   \.  .* \. .*
```

Comment: This exact answer has already been provided https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/711621/480066

Comment: @HatLess »Already« doesn't quite fit. I first wrote this in a commentary to the other answer, but after I saw the changed requirement, removed the comment and made my own answer out of it. After that, Archemar edited the answer. Thank you for hinting me on that. I leave this answer open anyhow, because I think the explanation is more verbose here.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;s/[^.]*\.([^.]*\..*)$/\1/;ta' input_file
stackexchange.com
example.org
example.tld
```