# Remove the Top Level Domain (TLD) and Second Level Domain (SLD) with awk or sed

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, sed, domain

I have a list of domains without subdomains in a text file. I need the TLD and SLD removed.

Input

```
google.uk
example.com
amazon.co.uk
domain.ca.uk
education.edu.it
```

Expected output:

```
google
example
amazon
domain
education
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove subdomains with awk or sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/711614/remove-subdomains-with-awk-or-sed)

Comment: @Archemar that is my own question haha. In that case I need the subdomains to be removed. Now I need the TLD removed. To make my question more useful for others I also asked how to remove the SLD

Comment: How about you read the other answers and explanation and use that knowledge to solve this transfer task by yourself?

Comment: @Philippos I could make it work with the cut command but not with the sed one. I want to have sed or awk. Stop downvoting my question when you are not even sure if I tried myself.

Comment: I'm voting on the question, not on your secret attempts. If you include your own effort, I can judge the modified question.

Comment: @Philippos I could ask it all in one question but I thought it was better to ask it in 2 questions. So that others who want to remove the TLD/SLD can find this question. Maybe I got a wrong point of view for what forums are meant for. I could be busy for days understanding this sed command while I only need like 4-5 sed commands for my work. I got other things to do.
-
Stackexchange about: Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network help people find the answers they need, when they need them

Comment: “You cannot help people permanently by doing for them, what they could and should do for themselves.” (Abraham Lincoln)

Comment: I couldn't find the answer so I'm trying to fill up missing questions on the forum. That's how I try to contribute. All in good terms. Stack Exchange say the forum is meant to help people find the answers they need. Not to give an modified answer that require days of learning for someone that is not familiar with sed. While they may only need a hand full of sed commands for their work. Maybe you're on the wrong forum or Stack Exchange need to change their vision.

Comment: @xorghelpneed actually no, Stack Exchange is absolutely not about giving people the answer they want when they want it. Not even close. It is about collecting a useful library of solutions to common problems, and we expect people to put effort into questions and try to solve it themselves first. The attitude of "I don't have time to waste putting effort to learn something, so I will waste other people's time instead" isn't welcome here.

Comment: @terdon As you can see I put in effort.

Comment: You did indeed, but I was responding only to your comment here where you said "*Stackexchange about: Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network help people find the answers they need, when they need them*" and since that is very much not true, I wanted to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I was a bit salty because debugging makes me mad :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need awk or sed for this, this is the job that `cut` exists to do:

```
$ cut -d'.' -f1 file
google
example
amazon
domain
education
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer to my own question. Turns out to be very simple

```
awk -F. '{print $1}' input_file
```

- I use the '.' as seperator with '-F.' like this I put the SLD and TLD in column $2 and/or $3
- With '{print $1}' I only print text in the first column which is the output I need

Comment: Do be cautious though, as results might be what you think unless the input is already in a very strict subset. If you have `www.example.com` as input, your answer (and all others answers too) will fail to provide to correct result. This is due to the fact, that in general, you can NOT do what you want with just a regex or a simple cut. You would need to consult the Public Suffix List to really get a list of suffixes and then extract the "registerable domain" first label out of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed "s/\..*//" filename

google
example
amazon
domain
education
```

The `\.` matches the first literal dot, the `.*` everything after. They get `s`ubstituted by nothing, thus everything starting from the first dot gets removed.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne 'put .split(".")[0];'  input_file
```

Maybe a Raku solution will be helpful: above is a fairly close translation of `awk` code, except Raku (and Perl) are zero-indexed. Raku's `-ne` "non-autoprinting linewise"  command-line flags are used (for more `sed`-like behavior, use Raku's `-pe` command-line flags).

Raku provides fewer command-line switches than Perl, meaning more gets accomplished within the language (increasing code portability). Here the field-separator is defined using `split` which destructively-removes `.` from the resultant strings. Then the `[0]` zero-indexed first element is `put` (`put` is short for "print-using-terminator", i.e. a newline is added at the end for you).

Sample Input:

```
google.uk
example.com
amazon.co.uk
domain.ca.uk
education.edu.it
```

Sample Output:

```
google
example
amazon
domain
education
```

https://raku.org