# return unique tld name from big domain name CSV file

Tags: grep, terminal, csv

i have a very big domain name CSV file that contect full domain name like:

```
facebook.com
google.com
aws.com.in
aws.co
asw.co.in
aws.com
net.com
net.in
new.net.in
```

So unique tld name result should be as below:

```
.com
.co
.com.in
.in
.net.in
```

I have tried this :

```
grep -o '.*'
```

but its not working and freezing terminal every time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove subdomains with awk or sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/711614/remove-subdomains-with-awk-or-sed)

Comment: Please always mention your operating system: the tools available are different on different systems. Should we assume Linux? Also, how do you define unique top level domain names? Given a domain name like `aa.bb.cc.dd.ee`, what would you want to keep? Should we just remove the first word, the string before the first `.`, or should we instead only keep the last one, or the last 2 if there are more than one? Please [edit] your question and explain what logic we should use to do this. Finally, your `grep -o '.*'` will match everything since `.` means "any character", you wanted `grep -o '\..*'`.

Comment: `grep -o '.*'` is the most useless command ever. It could be translated to »only extract everything from a line« (the dot stands for »any character«, the star for »each number of it«).

Comment: Your grep command is freezing your terminal as it's waiting for you to type some text for it to operate on since you didn't provide any input for it (e.g. a file name or pipe) on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

```bash
cut -d . -f 2- yourfile | sort -u
```

This extracts all but the first dot-delimited field from the input data, sorts the resulting lines and discards duplicates.